# Comprehensive secutiry solution

Tags: security, antivirus

I was given the task to find a comprehensive security solution for our IT systems.

The solution should include the following:

```
-> Central control
-> Antivirus
-> Anti theft
-> Remote disabling of the system
-> BIOS protection
-> Support for 18 users
```

The supported OS should include: -> Windows -> Mac -> Linux -> iPhone -> Android

Any idea of the best solution whith these characteristics?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome aboard. It seems reasonably clear what you want, but somewhat lacking in detail. The more detail that you give us, the more helpful an answer that we can give you. For instance, if the solution must be cost free, add the [tag:gratis] tag, otherwise state your budget. You could also expand quite a bit on what is meant by "remote control". And do you really mean "anti-theft", or "recovery after theft", or both? What about rolling out auto-updates without user interaction, etc, etc? And, are you sure that it will always remain 18 users? :-)

Comment: What about license costs, is there a cap?

Comment: Did you try Eset Enpoint Security?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. Regarding the price, I guess there is nothing free for the combination of characteristics I mentioned, so we would pay for the solution of course, I am not aware of any cap on the costs, logically we will not pay a million bucks for a solution, but if it's something solid, recommended by other users, great support and constant improvements and upgrades (which we consider positive), then I guess it's better to pay for one solution which integrates everything, then a combination of various tools. Unless I am mistaking here, and you have such a combination to offer.

Comment: I am not sure what is the diffence between anti-theft and recovery after theft, I would appreciate if you could elaborate on that. As for remote action, I meant a way to control the individual apps on each computer from some kind of a remote dashboard, like disabling the system in case necessary. As for the number of users, I am not sure it will always remain the same, lately we lost 2 workers, but we are planning to get around 8 more in the first quarter of the upcoming year.

Comment: No, I have not looked into Eset Endpoint Security yet, thanks.